# Using UncaughtExceptionhandler on Android

Tags: java, android

I want use `UncaughtExceptionHandler` on Android.

If crush application, first, show `MainActivity`
second, showing `logcat` dialog on `MainActivity`

but not showing activity , logcat dialog

so I try use toast
it showing toast, but not showing activity
exactly , showing activity_main.xml and showing logcat dialog on activity_main

MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UnhandledExceptionHandler(this));
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
}
```

UnhandledExceptionHandler.java   (toast test)

```
public class UnhandledExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {
private static final String TAG = "UnUnHandler";
private final Activity activity;

public UnhandledExceptionHandler(final Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

public void uncaughtException(Thread unusedThread, final Throwable e) {

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "occur errororor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Looper.loop();
        }
    }.start();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

UnhandledExceptionHandler.java  (test dialog)

```
    public class UnhandledExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {
   private final Activity activity;

   public UnhandledExceptionHandler(final Activity activity) {
      this.activity = activity;
   }

   public void uncaughtException(Thread unusedThread, final Throwable e) {
          activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            String title = "Fatal error: ";
            String msg = "fffff"

            TextView errorView = new TextView(UnhandledExceptionHandler.this.activity);
            errorView.setText(msg);
            errorView.setTextSize(2, 8.0F);

            ScrollView scrollingContainer = new  ScrollView(UnhandledExceptionHandler.this.activity);
            scrollingContainer.addView(errorView);

            DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            };
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UnhandledExceptionHandler.this.activity);
            builder.setTitle(title)
            .setView(scrollingContainer)
            .setPositiveButton("Exit", listener).show();
         }
       });
    }
 }
```